# Need to update primary key, but if the updated value exists, then delete the record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a record of varchar(255)'s which serves as a primary key for my table.  I need to be able to update the primary key of a record to a new value, however if the new primary key already exists on the table, then this is actually a duplicate record which I then want to kill.

I'm totally confused on how to actually do this, and any assistance with an example would be most appreciated.

Is it possible to do this in a single query as the most ideal solution?

Comment: If you're updating record A so that A.id := X, and there's already a record B with B.id = X ... which should be deleted? A or B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so doing this atomically without using anything but keys and without changing your database structure will have to look something like this:

```
begin;
delete from t where keycol = $keycol;
update t set keycol = $keycol where keycol = $oldkeycol;
commit;
```

Without the transaction you do not get a guarantee that you won't lose data.  But the update can only succeed if you delete the original data first.

Answer (score 0):

You may want the `replace` statement.  If the new key exists in the table, the you can replace the values in the key.

Something like:

```
replace t(keycol, col1, col2, col3)
    values ($keycol, $col1, $col2, $col3);
```

If `$keycol` already exists in the table, then the existing record is deleted and the new values are inserted.  If it doesn't exist, then the new values are inserted.

If you specifically want to do what you are saying, then something like:

```
delete from t where keycol = $keycol;

if mysql_affected_rows() = 0
    update t
        set keycol = $keycol where keycol = $oldkeycol;
```

Comment: I don't think your second suggestion matches the question.  The update should be unconditional.  And of course the delete and update should be in a begin/commit transaction.

Comment: The problem is that I want to update just the primary key value, there is alot of other data in the row that I need to maintain and dont have the data within PHP to recreate a new row with.  Was hoping there was a way to do this with an update